# How to catch an exception inside runResourceT

Tags: haskell

I would like to catch an exception inside *runResourceT* without releasing the resource, but the function *catch* runs the computation inside *IO*. Is there a way to catch an exception inside *runResourceT*, or what is the recommended way to refactor the code ?

Thank you for your help.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Main where

import Control.Exception as EX
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource

type Resource = String

allocResource :: IO Resource
allocResource = let r = "Resource"
                    in putStrLn (r ++ " opened.") >> return r

closeResource :: Resource -> IO ()
closeResource r = putStrLn $ r ++ " closed."

withResource :: ( MonadIO m
                , MonadBaseControl IO m
                , MonadThrow m
                , MonadUnsafeIO m
                ) => (Resource -> ResourceT m a) -> m a 
withResource f = runResourceT $ do
    (_, r) <- allocate allocResource closeResource
    f r

useResource :: ( MonadIO m
               , MonadBaseControl IO m
               , MonadThrow m
               , MonadUnsafeIO m
               ) => Resource -> ResourceT m Int
useResource r = liftIO $ putStrLn ("Using " ++ r) >> return 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Start..."

  withResource $ \r -> do

    x <- useResource r

    {-- This does not compile as the catch computation runs inside IO
    y <- liftIO $ EX.catch (useResource r)
                           (\e -> do putStrLn $ show (e::SomeException)
                                     return 0)
    --} 

    return ()

  putStrLn "Done."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ResourceT` is an instance of [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/resourcet/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#t:MonadBaseControl) from the [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) package, which is designed for lifting control structures like `forkIO` and `catch` into transformed monads.

The [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) package, which is built on top of monad-control, contains modules with versions of standard control structures that work in any `MonadBaseControl`. For exception handling, you can use the functions in the [`Control.Exception.Lifted`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lifted-base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception-Lifted.html) module. So, just `import qualified Control.Exception.Lifted as EX`<sup>1</sup> instead, and your code should work fine.

<sup>1</sup> Note the `qualified` here; quite confusingly, `import A as B` actually imports all of the definitions in `A` into scope, and simply defines `B` as an alias for the module! You need to use `qualified` to ensure that the definitions are not brought into scope, and are  instead accessed exclusively through the `B` alias.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments. It works as expected and helps me better understand monads transformers.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you can use the [`MonadCatch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadCatch) instance of [`ResourceT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#t:ResourceT), found in the [exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) package.  You simply need to substitute the generalized version of `catch` from `Control.Monad.Catch`:

```
import Control.Monad.Catch
…
main = do
  …
  withResource $ \r -> do
    …
    y <- Control.Monad.Catch.catch (useResource r) (\e -> …)
```