# Catch IO exceptions within an instance of MonadResource

Tags: exception, haskell, conduit

## Short version

Same question as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953168/how-to-catch-an-exception-inside-runresourcet), but within a generic `MonadResource` instance rather than an explicit `ResourceT m`.

## Long version

How would you define a `catch` function such that:

```
import Control.Exception            (Exception, IOException)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResource, runResourceT)

catch :: (MonadResource m, Exception e) -> m () -> (e -> m ()) -> m ()
catch = undefined

-- 'a' and 'b' are functions from an external library,
-- so I can't actually change their implementation
a, b :: MonadResource m => m ()
a = -- Something that might throw IO exceptions
b = -- Something that might throw IO exceptions

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
    a `catch` \(e :: IOException) -> -- Exception handling
    b `catch` \(e :: IOException) -> -- Exception handling
```

The problems I run into are:

- In [`Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#v%3acatch), `catch` only works on bare `IO`s ;
- In [`Control.Exception.Lifted`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.2.1/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v%3acatch), `catch` requires an instance of `MonadBaseControl`, which `MonadResource` is unfortunately **not** (and I wonder why) ;
- [`MonadResource`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t%3aMonadResource) implies [`MonadThrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t%3aMonadThrow) which defines a `monadThrow` function without its 'catch' equivalent (and I wonder why) ;

It looks like the only way to handle `IO` exceptions is to exit the `ResourceT` layer, and this bothers me: I'd like to be able to handle exceptions locally without travelling through the monad transformers stack.

For information, in my real code, `a` and `b` are actually the `http` function from [`Network.HTTP.Conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.0.0.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3ahttp).

Thank you for your insights.

### Minimal code with the problem

Compilable with `ghc --make example.hs` with `http-conduit` library installed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Exception.Lifted     (IOException, catch)
import Control.Monad.Base           (liftBase)
import Control.Monad.Error          (MonadError(..), runErrorT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control  (MonadBaseControl)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResource, runResourceT)

import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List            (consume)
import Data.Conduit.Text            (decode, utf8)
import Data.Text                    (Text)

import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Conduit         (http)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- runErrorT $ runResourceT f
    putStrLn $ "OK: " ++ show result

f :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadResource m, MonadError String m) => m [Text]
f = do
    req      <- liftBase $ parseUrl "http://uri-that-does-not-exist.abc"
    manager  <- liftBase $ newManager defaultManagerSettings
    response <- (http req manager `catch` \(e :: IOException) -> throwError $ show e)
    response $$+- decode utf8 =$ consume
```

When executed, this program ends in error with the following output:

```
InternalIOException getAddrInfo: does not exist (Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Would adding a `MonadBaseControl IO m` constraint be enough? The `MonadResource` documentation seems to imply that would be a natural thing to do.

Comment: @duplode I have no control over the implementation of `a` and `b`, as they are actually functions from the `http-conduit` library. For some reason, the maintainer of `resourcet` deliberately didn't add `MonadBaseControl` as a dependency of `MonadResource`.

Comment: You're catching the wrong exception. You need to catch `HttpException` or `SomeException`.

Comment: Indeed, replacing `IOException` with `HttpException` works, thank you. I suggest you post it as an answer so that I can validate it.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt: you may have missed koral's reply to you, but since your comment has the correct answer, it would be good to post it as a proper answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http` does not throw `IOException`, it throws [`HttpException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.5/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t:HttpException) and `InternalIOException` is one of the latter's constructors.

You should either catch `HttpException` or `SomeException` in case you want to catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The type you need,

```
a, b :: MonadResource m, MonadBaseControl IO m => m ()
```

Is a special case of the type you currently have

```
a, b :: MonadResource m => m ()
```

as the only difference is the extra class constraint. You are free to make the type signatures in your code less general than they would be by default; therefore, changing the signatures of `a` and `b` should be enough.

Comment: Cf comments under my question: I have no control over the signature of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @koral I am failing to get what the problem is. Given what you describe, in the worst case you should be able to wrap the functions in wrappers with less general signatures (as in `addInt :: Int -> Int -> Int; addInt = (+)`), and even that should be unnecessary given type inference. Can you add an minimal compilable example closer to what you actually have (e.g. using the relevant `http-conduit` functions)?

Comment: Minimal compilable example added :) .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, there is no problem with using *lifted-base*. Although the type of `a` and `b` only use the constraint `MonadResource m`, it doesn't mean you can't use them on a monad that has other additional properties. For example, if you perform your computation inside `ResourceT`, it satisfies the constraint for `a` and `b`, and you can also use anything from `Control.Exception.Lifted`:

```
-- ...
import Control.Exception.Lifted

-- 'a' and 'b' are functions from an external library,
-- so I can't actually change their implementation
a, b :: MonadResource m => m ()
a = undefined -- Something that might throw IO exceptions
b = undefined -- Something that might throw IO exceptions

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
    a `catch` \(e :: IOException) -> undefined -- Exception handling
    b `catch` \(e :: IOException) -> undefined -- Exception handling
```

Comment: I've added a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you alter the type signature of `catch` to include [`MonadCatch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadCatch) from the [exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) package, then it would be trivial:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadResource, runResourceT)
import Control.Monad.Catch          (catch)

a, b :: MonadResource m => m ()
a = …
b = …

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ do
    a `catch` \e -> …
    b `catch` \e -> …
```

Note that this does *not* require any changes for `a` nor `b`.

Also, both duplode and Petr Pudlák have pointed out that you are free to make the monad for `catch` to be *as specific as you like*, because doing so does not require any cooperation from `a` or `b`.  So any of these solutions will work.